# log message in gradle build doesn't show in gradle console of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

My build.gradle would like to log messages, I tried:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            ...

        }

        release {
           ...
           project.logger.info("I am releasing build!");
        }
    }

buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
          project.logger.info("I am releasing build too!");
        }
 }
```

I choose "release" from build variant. But when I run build, I can't find the log message from "Gradle Console" on the right-bottom of Android Studio. Why?  (I am using Android Studio 3.0.1)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are logging with `info` level. To show `info` messages you have to run your tasks with `--info` or lower flag.

To print your message without any additional flag you should use `lifecycle` logging level eg `project.logger.lifecycle('I am releasing build too!')` or just print to System.out `println('I am releasing build too!')`

You may read more about logging at gradle tasks here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html

Comment: Where exactly should these messages be displayed?